# Packet filtering firewall - (Network Layer)

Tags: firewalls, packet

I would like to know what does this particular rule of the packet filtering firewall ruleset do:

```
Source Address: Any
Source Port: Any
Destination Address: 192.168.1.0
Destination Port: 1023 and above
Action: Allow
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows any traffic targeted at the IP address `192.168.1.0` and any port numbered `1023` or higher through the firewall.